# Prevent Outlook from replacing images with text " << OLE Object: Picture (Device Independent Bitmap) >> "

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

When replying to emails, Outlook sometimes replaces embedded images with text

```
 << OLE Object: Picture (Device Independent Bitmap) >>
```

How can I prevent this? *I am looking for a solution that would not require manual conversion to HTML with every email.*

#### Additional info

- Using Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise, Outlook Version 2102.
- I have in Outlook Options -> Mail -> Compose messages -> Compose Messages in this format: HTML

#### Current workaround

*Seems that this happens when the original message has been sent with non-HTML (e.g. Rich Text) format. In this case there is a manual workaround. Posting it here for quick help for people searching for a solution until there exists a better one*:

1. Double-click message to open it in new window
2. Select Actions -> Edit Message

[image: Actions -> Edit Message]

3. Select Format Text -> As HTML

[image: Format Text -> As HTML]

4. Reply to the email as usual.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such option in the outlook client to always reply to all messages in HTML format. But as harrymc said, we can reply in HTML format automatically with VBA.

According to my test in outlook 365, please refer to the following steps:

1.Press the Alt + F11 keys to open the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications window；

2.Click the Insert > Module>and paste the following code:

```
Sub AlwaysReplyInHTML()
Dim oSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim oItem As Object
'Get the selected item
Select Case TypeName(Application.ActiveWindow)
Case "Explorer"
Set oSelection = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
If oSelection.Count > 0 Then
Set oItem = oSelection.Item(1)
Else
MsgBox "Please select an item first!", vbCritical, "Reply in HTML"
Exit Sub
End If
Case "Inspector"
Set oItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Case Else
MsgBox "Unsupported Window type." & vbNewLine & "Please select or open an item first.", _
vbCritical, "Reply in HTML"
Exit Sub
End Select
    Dim oMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oMsgReply As Outlook.MailItem
Dim bPlainText As Boolean
'Change the message format and reply
If oItem.Class = olMail Then
Set oMsg = oItem
If oMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain Then
bPlainText = True
End If
oMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
Set oMsgReply = oMsg.Reply
If bIsPlainText = True Then
oMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
End If
oMsg.Close (olSave)
oMsgReply.Display
'Selected item isn't a mail item
Else
MsgBox "No message item selected. Please select a message first.", _
vbCritical, "Reply in HTML"
Exit Sub
End If
'Cleanup
Set oMsgReply = Nothing
Set oMsg = Nothing
Set oItem = Nothing
Set oSelection = Nothing
End Sub
```

3.On Outlook top, click down arrow>More Commands…;

[image]

4.Choose the macros and add to the Quick Access Folders>Ok;
[image]

5.Then the macro will be displayed in the top;

[image]

In this way, when you want to reply the message, just need to select the message and click the macro. The reply message will be the HTML format.

Hope the above help!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not offer any built-in solution apart from the one you found.

Some other solutions:

- Use the VBA macro
  [Always Reply in HTML](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/replyinhtml.htm).
  Full installation instructions are included.
- Use the commercial add-on
  [Bells & Whistles for Outlook](https://www.outlook-apps.com/product/bells-whistles-for-outlook/)
  ($29.95)
- Use the commercial
  [Reply with Attachment](https://www.extendoffice.com/product/kutools-for-outlook/outlook-reply-with-attachment.html)
  feature of
  [Kutools for Outlook](https://www.extendoffice.com/product/kutools-for-outlook.html)
  ($49)